# Regularity and invertibility of two parameterized matrices?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

> $$
> C=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1+a & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
> 1 & 2+a & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
> 1 & 2 & 3+a & 4 &  5 \\
> 1 & 2 & 3 & 4+a &  5 \\
> 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5+a \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>
> For which values of $a$ is the matrix $C$ regular?

> $$
> A=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 3a & a \\
> -a & 1 \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>
> Determine for which values of $a$ is there an inverse $A^{-1}$ and then solve it?

Please help....

Comment: For this matrix A I've tried finding the determinant and then equal it with zero so I get a=0 and a=-3.  I think that inverse of A exists for all values of a except 0 and -3. But it says calculate it (the inverse). I don't know how ?  For the first problem I am not quite sure how to start... Could you help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know about adjugate matrix?

Comment: for matrix $A$ you can use cramer's rule to direct express the inverse, for matrix $C$ you can use the Gauss algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is an easier way to find the values for the matrix $C$ for which it is invertible:

Look at the following representation
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1+a & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2+a & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3+a & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4+a &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5+a \\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
\end{pmatrix}+
a \operatorname{Id}_{5\times5}=B+a \operatorname{Id}_{5\times5}
$$
which is the eigenvalue problem for matrix B in $\lambda=-a$.
That for $\lambda=0$ we have an eigenvalue is clear, the dimension of the eigenspace is $4$, which is clear because with Gauss we get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
\end{pmatrix}\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 
\end{pmatrix}\
$$
so in fact we are looking for one other eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ with eigenspace dimension $1$, so that everything adds up to $5$ eventually.

If we look hard enough, we can easily figure out it has to be $\lambda=15\Leftrightarrow a=-15$. For this to be seen, observe that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1+a \\
1  \\
1  \\
1  \\
1  
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
2+a  \\
2  \\
2  \\
2  
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
3 \\
3  \\
3+a  \\
3  \\
3
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\
4  \\
4  \\
4+a  \\
4 
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
10+a \\
10+a  \\
10+a  \\
10+a \\
10 
\end{pmatrix}\equiv(-1)\begin{pmatrix}
5 \\
5  \\
5  \\
5 \\
5+a 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is true for $a=-15$. Since now we have 5 dimensional eigenspace we are finished and conclude that for $a_1=0$ and $a_2=-15$ the matrix $C$ is not invertible.

For the second part just use [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) which will give you
$$
A^{-1}=\frac 1{a(3+a)}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -a \\ a & 3a \end{pmatrix}
$$ 
which indeed is defined for all $a\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0,-3\}$

Answer (score 0):

I) We need evaluate determinant. Determinant is a multilinear function of the columns. So,
$$
\require{cancel}
\det C=
\begin{vmatrix}
1+a & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2+a & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3+a & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4+a &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix} = \\=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2+a & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3+a & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4+a &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
a & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
0 & 2+a & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
0 & 2 & 3+a & 4 &  5 \\
0 & 2 & 3 & 4+a &  5 \\
0 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix}=\\=
\cancelto{0}{\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3+a & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4+a &  5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix}}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
1 & a & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 0 & 3+a & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 0 & 3 & 4+a &  5 \\
1 & 0 & 3 & 4 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix}
+
a\begin{vmatrix}
2+a & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
2 & 3+a & 4 &  5 \\
2 & 3 & 4+a &  5 \\
2 & 3 & 4 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix}=\\=
a\begin{vmatrix}
1  & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
1  & 3+a & 4 &  5 \\
1  & 3 & 4+a &  5 \\
1  & 3 & 4 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix} +
a\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
2 & 3+a & 4 &  5 \\
2 & 3 & 4+a &  5 \\
2 & 3 & 4 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix}
+ a\begin{vmatrix}
a & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
0 & 3+a & 4 &  5 \\
0 & 3 & 4+a &  5 \\
0 & 3 & 4 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix} = \\\text{...analogous tricks...}\\=
a\begin{vmatrix}
1  & 0 & 4 &  5 \\
1  & a & 4 &  5 \\
1  & 0 & 4+a &  5 \\
1  & 0 & 4 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix} +
a\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 0 & 4 &  5 \\
2 & a & 4 &  5 \\
2 & 0 & 4+a &  5 \\
2 & 0 & 4 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix}
+ a^2\begin{vmatrix}
3+a & 4 &  5 \\
3 & 4+a &  5 \\
3 & 4 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix} =\\=
a^2\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 4 &  5 \\
1 & 4+a &  5 \\
1 & 4 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix} +
a^2\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 4 &  5 \\
2 & 4+a &  5 \\
2 & 4 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix}
+ a^2\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 4 &  5 \\
3 & 4+a &  5 \\
3 & 4 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix}
+ a^2\begin{vmatrix}
a & 4 &  5 \\
0 & 4+a &  5 \\
0 & 4 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix} =\\=
a^2\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 &  5 \\
1 & a &  5 \\
1 & 0 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix} +
a^2\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 0 &  5 \\
2 & a &  5 \\
2 & 0 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix}
+ a^2\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 0 &  5 \\
3 & a &  5 \\
3 & 0 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix}
+ a^3\begin{vmatrix}
4+a &  5 \\
4 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix} =\\=
a^3\begin{vmatrix}
1 &  5 \\
1 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix} +
a^3\begin{vmatrix}
2 &  5 \\
2 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix}
+ a^3\begin{vmatrix}
3 &  5 \\
3 & 5+a \\
\end{vmatrix}
+ a^3\begin{vmatrix}
4+a &  5 \\
4 &  5+a \\
\end{vmatrix} =\\=
a^3[a + 2a + 3a + a^2 + 9a] = a^4(a + 15)
$$

Hence, if $a\ne0$ and $a\ne-15$ matrix is regular.

II)
$$
\det A = a^2 + 3a
$$
If $a\ne0$ and $a\ne-3$, matrix is regular and
$$
A^{-1} = \frac{1}{a(a+3)}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -a\\
a & 3a
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: I guess you mean $a\neq-15$?!

Comment: @user190080, yes, it was a typo